# Possible to create a loop inside of parameter?

Tags: php

```
$a=4;
$check=array(1,2,3,4,5....);

if($a==$check[0] || $a==$check[1]...){echo "Match";}else{echo "Not Match";}
```

I need to create a loop inside of parameter to check if the numbers are match.

The number array can be very long.
is any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function: `if(in_array($a, $check))`

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = 4;
$check = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

if(in_array($a, $check))
{echo "Match";
} else {
    echo "Not Match";
}
```